# Request for an explanation of a program which uses the getchar() in a while statement

Tags: c, while-loop, strcpy, getchar

Will it be too much to ask if I pray for an elucidation of the following codes from Line 7 onward? I have difficulty in comprehending how getchar() may differ from gets() or scanf() for the most parts. Why is it important to add an escape sequence, \n with it, when in my belief, the value inputting would be done in a horizontal form(as it is a 1D string)? The increment and then the immediate usage of decrement operator bewilder me too. Also, require help with the strcpy(). :|
If somebody has the time, I implore guidance. Thank you!

```
main()
{
    char st[80], ch, word[15], lngst[15];
    int i, l, j;
    printf("\n Enter a sentence \n ");
    i = 0;
    while((st[i++] = getchar()) != '\n');
    i--;
    st[i] = '\0';
    l = strlen(st);
    i = 0; j = 0;
    strcpy(word," ");
    strcpy(lngst," ");
    while(i <= l)
    {
        ch = st[i];
        if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\0')
        {
            word[j] = '\0';
            if(strlen(word) > strlen(lngst))
            strcpy(lngst, word);
            strcpy(word," ");
            j = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            word[j] = ch;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        }   
        printf("\n Longest word is %s", lngst);
        printf("\n Press any key to continue...");
        getch();
}
```

Comment: Note: function: `gets()` has been depreciated for many years and completely removed from the latest versions of the C standard

Answer (score 3):

I can't say why the code is written as it is (there are other input options) but I can address some of your concerns:

> Why is it important to add an escape sequence, \n?

This "newline" character is returned by `getchar()` when you hit the `return`/`enter` key (the typical 'signal' used to indicate you've done entering your line of text). Without checking for this, the `getchar` function would just keep (trying to) read in more characters.

> How getchar() may differ from gets() or scanf()?

It is notoriously tricky to read in text that includes spaces using the `scanf` function ([this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630662/string-with-whitespace-at-struct-dont-work) may help), and the `gets` function has been declared obsolete (because it's dangerous). One *could* use `fgets(st, 80, stdin)` but, like I said, I can't comment on *why* the code is written exactly like it is.

> The increment and then the immediate usage of decrement operator
>   bewilder me too.

The expression `(st[i++] = getchar())` transfers the character read into the `st` array element indexed by `i` and ***afterwards*** increments the value of `i`, so the next call to `getchar` will put its result in the next array element. But, when the `\n` (newline) character has been read, `i` will have been incremented, ready for the *next* character - but there won't be one, so we then reduce it by one ***after*** we have finished our `while` loop.

> Also, require help with the strcpy().

The call `strcpy(dst, src)` will copy all characters in the string `src` (up to and including the ***required*** `nul` terminator, `'\0'`) into the `dst` string, replacing anything that is already there.

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> while((st[i++] = getchar()) != '\n');
> ```

has the same effect as

```
while (1) { // "infinite" loop
    int tmp = getchar(); // get keypress
    st[i] = tmp; // copy to string
    i++; // update index
    if (tmp == '\n') break; // exit the infinite loop after enter is processed
}
```